# SQL Server query plan cache randomly getting corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have an ASP.NET site running off SQL Server database with the following nightly maintenance plan:

1. Check database integrity
2. Rebuild index
3. Update stats
4. Clean up history

Every now and then I wake up to a stream of the following errors (and unhappy users!)

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

I've figured out that's it's because one of the SP cache plans has gone skewiff, i.e. one of the signatures is no longer correct (it's trying to force a varchar parameter into a datetime). I'm using LINQ 2 SQL (can't change that!) which results in all manner of weird and wonderful sp_executesql calls. The only way I know to fix it is to step in and execute the following SQL after the fact:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Any ideas what can I do to stop this issue happening in the first place?

Comment: That could be a union without explicit type cast or something like that. I'm sure there is a conversion issue in generated or persisted (sp/fn) code that is not aware of various datatypes incoming. You should catch an exception and detect a specific query where error occurs.